# How can I change the button text on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to change the button text on load of the page. I'm using static data and my button is not displayed.

**Model**

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public long Phone { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
List<UserModel> listuser = new List<UserModel>();
UserModel users = new UserModel();
users.Firstname = "Nisha mam";
users.Lastname = "Patel";
users.Phone = 90897564444;
users.IsActive = true;
listuser.Add(users);

users = new UserModel();
users.Firstname = "Namrata";
users.Lastname = "Bhavsar";
users.Phone = 9678975643;
users.IsActive = false;
listuser.Add(users);

users = new UserModel();
users.Firstname = "Anjali";
users.Lastname = "Mehta";
users.Phone = 9228975643;
users.IsActive = true;
listuser.Add(users);
return View(listuser);
```

**View**

```
@Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("List").Columns(c =>
{
    c.Bound(p => p.Firstname);
    c.Bound(p => p.Lastname);
    c.Bound(p => p.Phone);
    c.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Title("Unlock Payroll Entry").Filterable(false).ClientTemplate("<input type='submit' value='Unlock'></span>").Sortable(false);
})
```

Comment: Inside your ClientTemplate you specify `value='Unlock'`, which sets the caption of a html button. In addition you're closing a <span> tag which has not been opened. So replace `</span>` with `</input>`

Comment: @Capricorn : thank you but here my aim is now to change the button TEXT based on if else condition with boolean values will be tested inside for IsActive field..Please help me as soon as possible

Comment: You indicate that your button _"is not displayed"_ .  The suggestion from @Capricorn should be helpful in getting the button to display.

Comment: @DavidTansey : yes it is working now..Thank you guys ..But how I can implement if else conditional clienttemplate to change text of button when ISActive is true and false viseversa.. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

The `ClientTemplate` in a Kendo grid can include arbitrary javascript to execute which will allow you to build the html for your conditionally.

Try something like this for the binding on your `IsActive` column.

```
c.Bound(p => p.IsActive)
    .Title("Unlock Payroll Entry")
    .Filterable(false)
    .ClientTemplate(
        "# if (IsActive) { #" +
        "<input type='submit' value='Unlock' />" + 
        "# } else { #" + 
        "<input type='submit' value='SomeOtherValue' />" + 
        "#}#")
    .Sortable(false);
```

Kendo also supports specifying a template like this one 'externally' (i.e. in a separate block that you refer to by name / id in your grid definition).  This approach might be easier to work with for more complex javascript logic.

Comment: If you mark my answer as Accepted then you will receive +2 reputation points.  If you think the answer reflects what a 'good answer' should look like then I be grateful if you would also Upvote the answer.  Thanks.